# I'm having a runtime error in my code. When I enter letters only the boolean valid turns true

Tags: java

This code will Input password and check if the password contains **letters** and **numbers**. If password don't have both **register** will continue.

When I enter **letters** and **numbers** the register is complete, when I enter **numbers only** the register continue, and when I enter **letters only** the register is complete without containing numbers.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Sample {
static BufferedReader dataIn = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(System.in));
public static void main (String[] args)throws Exception {
    boolean valid = false;
    boolean alphaCheck = false;
    boolean numCheck = false;
    char[] alpha = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};
    char[] num = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'};
    do {
        System.out.println("Password must contain Letters and Numbers Only. (abc../ABC.., 123..)");
        System.out.println("Special Characters are not Allowed.");
        System.out.print("Register Password: ");
        String password = dataIn.readLine();

        char[] passwordToArray = password.toUpperCase().toCharArray();
        // Check if password contains numbers
        for(char x: passwordToArray){
            for(char y: num){
                if(x==y){
                    numCheck = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        // Check if password contains Letters
        for(char x: passwordToArray){
            for(char y: alpha){
                if(x==y){
                    alphaCheck = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(!numCheck){
            System.out.println("No Numbers Found.");
        }
        if(!alphaCheck){
            System.out.println("No Letters Found.");
        }
        // Check if password contains both Alphabets and Numbers
        // if false Continue Register
        if((numCheck)&&(alphaCheck)){
            System.out.println("Register Complete");
            valid = true;
        }else{
            System.out.println("Register Failed. Please Try again");
        }

    }while (!valid) ;
}
}
```

Comment: is this homework assignment? do you have restrictions from using regular expression and/or collections or 3rd party libraries etc I am asking because there are better solutions than iterating over arrays

Comment: no, this is not my homework. i just want to try my skills using array loops and if else. I just want to try verifying password using for loops and if else. Please help if you know the solution i cant understand why im having runtime error

Comment: Paste the stack trace.

Comment: I just want to understand why im having runtime error.

Comment: If you paste the stack trace, it will help us debug the issue. The stack trace contains the line throwing RunTimeException. By the way, your code is remarkably inefficient.

Comment: I think by "runtime error" OP means he/she are getting unexpected results

Comment: yes Im having unexpected results. I want to understand why. when i understand ill fix it by myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare (and initialize) your validation variables once before the loop, but you might loop multiple times. First with letters, then with only numbers. Or in the reverse order. Regardless, you should reset those sentinel values in the loop body. Something like

```
boolean valid = false;
boolean alphaCheck = false;
boolean numCheck = false;
char[] alpha = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 
        'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };
char[] num = { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0' };
do {
    valid = alphaCheck = numCheck = false;
```

I would also recommend you write a function to check if the value is present in your array of allowed values. That could make the rest of the code much easier to read,

```
private static boolean contains(char[] arr, char ch) {
    for (char v : arr) {
        if (ch == v) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**And**, we can *potentially* make the array initializations prettier by using [`String.toCharArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray--). Like,

```
char[] alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();
char[] num = "1234567890".toCharArray();
```

Comment: I dont wnat to use function/method/class this time. i just want to test my basic skills using array,loops,if else.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you never set the value of the boolean to its original state, which should be false, inside the do while loop.

So let's say you insert a password with just numbers, the password is not passed the first time because it's not valid, but the boolean values numCheck will be true for each future iteration, and of course the same applies if you input just chars.

This program will pass the inserted password in three cases then

1. If you first insert a password with just letters and then you insert a password with just numbers
2. if you first insert a password with just numbers and then you insert a password with just letters
3. if you type the correct password with both numbers and letters

This is how you should correct your code.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Sample {
    static BufferedReader dataIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        boolean valid = false;
        char[] alpha = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};
        char[] num = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'};
        do {
            boolean alphaCheck = false;
            boolean numCheck = false;
            System.out.println("Password must contain Letters and Numbers Only. (abc../ABC.., 123..)");
            System.out.println("Special Characters are not Allowed.");
            System.out.print("Register Password: ");
            String password = dataIn.readLine();

            char[] passwordToArray = password.toUpperCase().toCharArray();
            System.out.println(passwordToArray);
            // Check if password contains numbers
            for (char x : passwordToArray) {
                for (char y : num) {
                    if (x == y) {
                        numCheck = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            // Check if password contains Letters
            for (char x : passwordToArray) {
                for (char y : alpha) {
                    if (x == y) {
                        System.out.println(x + " == " + y);
                        alphaCheck = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!numCheck) {
                System.out.println("No Numbers Found.");
            }
            if (!alphaCheck) {
                System.out.println("No Letters Found.");
            }
            // Check if password contains both Alphabets and Numbers
            // if false Continue Register
            if (numCheck && alphaCheck) {
                System.out.println("Register Complete");
                valid = true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Register Failed. Please Try again");
            }

        } while (!valid);
    }
}
```

Comment: all boolean set to false. I dont know if the error is in numCheck or if((numCheck)&&(alphaCheck))

Comment: It's not, the do while continues with the wrong boolean values

Comment: Just put alphaCheck and numCheck inside the do while loop and it will work

Comment: I understand now Thank you for your help. the num&alphaCheck shoud be inside the do while because everytime I enter the password if its inivalid the boolean should remain false. Thank You so much for your help. Its my 1st time here.